# changing theme in wpf usercontrol for telerik rad controls

Tags: wpf, user-controls, telerik

Im use a wpf usercontrol in my program and use telerik controls for wpf , 
I want to change theme radcontrols in runtime or none-runtime(use xaml),
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Telerik.Windows.Controls.StyleManager to control the Telerik theming.

Some examples:

```
StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new Office_BlackTheme();
StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new Office_BlueTheme();
StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new Office_SilverTheme();
StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new SummerTheme();
StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new VistaTheme();
StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new Windows7Theme();
StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new TransparentTheme();
```